# char comparison and handling variables

Tags: c, ubuntu, unix, binary, char

So I'm pretty new to programming in general and even more so with C and UNIX based operating systems.

I'm trying to learn how to write code in C and I'm working on ubuntu OS. I found a few beginner-level tasks online  to get started. So right now I'm trying to complete this task:

Complete the implementation of the function code2abc, such that it returns the
character corresponding to a 2-bit code specified in a parameter code of type
char. The character returned by the function should be determined based on
the following bit content of code:

code/return value: 00000001/'A' --- 00000010/'B' --- 00000011/'C'

Expected output:

1. code2abc(1) = 'A'
2. code2abc(2) = 'B'
3. code2abc(3) = 'C'
4. code2abc(0) = ' '
5. cod2abc(*ANYTHING ELSE*) = ' '

First, I don't really get the meaning of 2-bit code and how to use it. I've looked online but found nothing to help. Second as far as I can understand the instructions imply that the function's input is a char value, how does this respond to the binary code mentined there? So far I've tried:

```
char code2abc(char code) {
    if ((code <'1' != 0) || (code >'3' != 0)) { // referring to ASCII values of the chars
        return ' ';
}
    return (code + 52); // 52 is the difference of ASCII values between A,B,C and 1,2,3  
}
```

I'm used to working with java so I tried using what I know but I have a feeling I'm way off. When I compile the file the system alerts me that the variable 'code' wasn't used and when I run it it returns ' '(blank space). I'm working with VIM editor, could it be that there is a syntax error that would make the compiler not recognize the variable?

Would really apreciate any thoughts or tips!

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this with a simple switch statement, for example:

```c
char code2abc(const int code){
    switch(code){
        case 0b01: return 'A';
        case 0b10: return 'B';
        case 0b11: return 'C';
        default: return '';
    }
}
```

There's no real conversion happening here, just a simple if-else relationship. I think what they want you to do is to look at the binary and convert it to decimal? If so, the above code would be equivalent to:

```c
char code2abc(const int code){
    switch(code){
        case 1: return 'A';
        case 2: return 'B';
        case 3: return 'C';
        default: return '';
    }
}
```

As far as the "meaning" of two-bit code, there is none. It's just an arbitrary mapping assigned to the letters 'A', 'B', and 'C'. You won't find it in any convention.

Comment: But the input is supposed to be a char not an int. Also I forgot to mention I'm using VIM editor, could you think of a reason the compiler is telling me the variable 'code' is unused when clearly I used it?

Comment: At the end of the day, a char is nothing but an 8-bit integer. The only thing that gives it any meaning is the encoding (i.e. ASCII, UTF-8). Just replace `int` with `char` in the program and it'll work.

Comment: It should be mentioned that binary constants (0b01, e.g.) are a GCC extension, and not a standard part of the C language. Also,` '' ` (empty character constant) is an error.

Comment: True, although it works in most modern compilers including clang and MSVC. So you're fine to use it as long as it's not strict ISO C.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker It's not an empty char it's '(space)', is that still an error? How else should I represent a spcae character?

Comment: @GuyMarino Thanks for the explanation! Also what is a binary constant? Is it simply a byte representation of a value?

Comment: <quote><space><quote> is fine, that's 32.